# Is there a way to duplicate the windows desktop zooming in SDL to make low res pixels look like stylyzed cartoon art?

Tags: sdl, windows

When you hit the Win key and numpad plus key at the same time it opens the desktop magnifying glass and the effect of this on low res pixel art is to make it look like super cool stylized cartoon art. I want the game to look like this all the time. Is there a way to do this permanent i SDL or DirectX or OpenGL?

How I have achieved this image is to run the game in a small windows and have the windows 10 magnifying glass hoover over it and I hit print screen. And I want the game to look like this all the time in full screen.

[image: I want my game to look like this]
Ps. This is the Gradius 3 ship that I use for place holder graphics for question asking purposes.

Comment: Look up [pixel art scaling algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel-art_scaling_algorithms).

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve this by using a viewport: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetViewport

You define a rectangle somewhere in your scene which will then fill the window. You can update where the rectangle is as your player moves around.

Comment: This will zoom the picture, yes. But without the fancy upscaling algorithm OP asked about.